# Issue with Django Template for loop

Tags: python, html, django, templates

so I did some searches but couldn't find the answer to my particular issue... What is happening is that:

I have a model named section which have section_title field. This field can have spaces, for example: "First Section".

When I pass this to Django, I am removing the space in Python with replace(), and created a filter on Django which also removes the space like so:

```
@register.filter(name='replace_char')
def replace_char(value, arg):
    return value.replace(arg, '')
```

Then on my template:

```
{% for subsection in section.section_title|replace_char:" " %}
```

The issue is that subsection is being shown as each character from section_title, instead of the list that section_title references. Here is the dictionary being passed to the template:

**{'sections': [< Section: First Section>, < Section: Second Section>], 'FirstSection': [< Subsection: Subsection 1>, < Subsection: Subsection 2>], 'SecondSection': [< Subsection: Bla1>], 'teste': ['1', '2', '3']}**

If I hardcode:

```
{% for subsection in FirstSection %}
```

It works...

Any ideas? Thanks!

**OBS:** I removed the spaces because I thought they were causing the issue, but apparently not. It wasnt working with the spaces as well...

Full template code:

```
{% for section in sections %}
    <div class="sectionHeader">
        {{ section.section_title }}
    </div>
    <div class="forumSection">
    {% for subsection in section.section_title|replace_char:" " %}
        <div>
            {{ subsection }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

**Models:**

```
class Section(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.section_title
    section_title   = models.CharField(primary_key = True, unique = True, max_length = 50)
class Subsection(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.subsection_title
    subsection_title    = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    subsection_section  = models.ForeignKey(
                        'Section',
                        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
    )
```

Comment: I believe what you are following is the only solution.

Comment: @AnupYadav, sorry, I didn't understand what you meant.

Comment: can you show what context variable you are passing from your view?

Comment: The dictionary being passed to the template doesn't contain "section". Did you mean "sections"?

Comment: @UmarAsghar, isnt the context variable the one in bold on my first comment?

Comment: @kshikama, sorry, but I left some code out... I am editing and adding it so you can better understand.

Comment: I believe that the issue is being caused because "section.section_title" is being treated as a string instead of a key from the dictionary, but I dont know how to change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set up a related_name on your foreign key so that you can fetch all your subsections corresponding to the section.

```
class Section(models.Model):
    section_title   = models.CharField(primary_key = True, unique = True, max_length = 50)
class Subsection(models.Model):
    subsection_title    = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    subsection_section  = models.ForeignKey(
                        'Section',
                        related_name = 'subsections',
                        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
    )
```

And then you can change your template code to loop over your subsections as follows:

```
{% for section in sections %}
    <div class="sectionHeader">
        {{ section.section_title }}
    </div>
    <div class="forumSection">
        <div>
            {% for subsection in section.subsections.all %}
                {{ subsection.subsection_title }}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#related-objects for more information.

Comment: Yes, I want to do the "unless" portion of your comment. However, section is a foreign_key of subsection, meaning that the section doesnt know which subsections it has... Only subsections knows that it is a child of a given Section... Would I necessarily need to change my models in this case?

Comment: I will add the models to the question description

Comment: Hmm sorry I wasn't quite clear. Can you edit your question with the code for the Section model?

Comment: Yeah that would be helpful.

Comment: @GuiFGDeo use reverse relation in that case. Update the query to cover **prefetch_related** case as well for bringing the subsections beside sections.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot for that! **related_name** saved me big time!

I haven't fully understanded what related_name does (checked the db with db viewer, nothing changed), but I will check that link on related-objects...

Comment: Would this be the same as using **subsections_set** if I didn't have that related_name on code?

Comment: Yes it would indeed.

Comment: Well it might be `subsection_set`.

Comment: Great, just to fully understand how this works! Thanks again @kshikama!